# VirtualStringTree con CheckBox

Tags: c++builder

I've been trying to find a code for ten days to process only the nodes that are selected and for more laps I've taken, I'm not able to find the solution. The most I have come to know is that node is totally or partially selected (csChecked, or csMixed states), but then I get stuck and, for example, in node **Banco (no domiciliado)**, I don't know how to process only the marked nodes, in this case it would be Manzanares. Can you give me some code that gives me a hint to do it?

[image: VirtualStringTree con CheckBox]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation you do not care about csMixed, only csChecked.  In your example the values for each 'parent' node are the total for the subnodes.

If this is the case, then you want to only check those nodes which
have no children
AND are checked.

So you would probably want code looking something like:

```cpp
  for int(nLoop=0; nLoop<pControl->Items->Count; nLoop++)
  {
    if( (!(pControl->Items->Item[nLoop]->HasChildren)) &&
        (pControl->Items->Item[nLoop]->State==csChecked) )
    {
      // call your process routine
    }
  }
```

I don't have any reference for the control you are trying to use so I don't know the properties on it, but I have guessed what you need.  You should be able to find your way from here if I have understood what you want to do correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try your suggestion.